# Best way to salvage 4x4s from old deck

Tags: deck, lumber, decking

I tore up my old deck to do some drainage work and now I'm ready to build a new deck in the old footprint. I couldn't remove the screws from the deck planks because they were buried way down in the wood, so I cut out pieces with a skill saw.

I want to try saving the 4x4 wood joists/supports but I haven't found an easy way to do this. I can't get a sawzall blade in between the 4x4s and the planks, and like I said, the screws are completely buried. Is there any clever way I can save these 4x4s?

[image: deck parts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big hammer.

Block those pieces up and hit small wood with a hammer.

Can also do it with a plybar, but with a hammer you can pretend it is non nice people.

There are also nail removers that you bang down into the wood.

Comment: worked great, thanks.